# Pariameter value find and replace with map in HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

I am very new to HAPRoxy. I have 100 of URI paths in a map file. I need to replace the parameter value. Say, below is the path:

```
/call/landingPage?callType=INBOUND&phoneCalledFrom=1111111111&phoneCalledFrom=2222222222
```

I need to replace 2222222222 with 3333333333. Now the new path will be

```
/call/landingPage?callType=INBOUND&phoneCalledFrom=1111111111&phoneCalledFrom=3333333333.
```

The find and replace is need to be done by reading the map file. Content of the map file as follows:

```
2222222222 3333333333
1111111111 4444444444
5555555555 6666666666
```

Help me to implement the above condition in the HAProxy.

Comment: I don't know what to use.

Comment: Unfortunately then, there's not much we can do for you. Here at SF we expect you to have tried to solve the problem yourself, and then come back here when you run into an actual technical problem which we can try and help you solve. Simply throwing your high-level problem at the community and saying "Solve this for me" doesn't tend to be well received.

Comment: I tried this http-request set-query %[query,regsub(phoneCalledFrom=2222222222,phoneCalledFrom=3333333333)]. But  I have problem is how I can replace the value form the map file.